# MongoDB geospatial query with sort - performance issues

Tags: mongodb, spatial, sorting

I have query (which is very slow **~2,5s**):

```
db.markers.find({ latlng: { '$within': { '$box': [ [ -16, -140 ], [ 75, 140 ] ] } } }).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1000)
```

When I run explain for this query I get

```
{
   "cursor" : "GeoBrowse-box",
   "isMultiKey" : false,
   "n" : 1000,
   "nscannedObjects" : 242331,
   "nscanned" : 242331,
   "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 242331,
   "nscannedAllPlans" : 242331,
   "scanAndOrder" : true,
   "indexOnly" : false,
   "nYields" : 1383,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 2351,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "latlng" : [ ]
    },
    "lookedAt" : NumberLong(262221),
    "matchesPerfd" : NumberLong(242331),
    "objectsLoaded" : NumberLong(242331),
    "pointsLoaded" : NumberLong(0),
    "pointsSavedForYield" : NumberLong(0),
    "pointsChangedOnYield" : NumberLong(0),
    "pointsRemovedOnYield" : NumberLong(0),
    "server" : "xx:27017"
}
```

When I remove **sort({_id: -1})** explain gives me (fast query **5 millis**):

```
{
    "cursor" : "GeoBrowse-box",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1000,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1000,
    "nscanned" : 1000,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1000,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1000,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 5,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "latlng" : [ ]
    },
    "lookedAt" : NumberLong(1000),
    "matchesPerfd" : NumberLong(1000),
    "objectsLoaded" : NumberLong(1000),
    "pointsLoaded" : NumberLong(0),
    "pointsSavedForYield" : NumberLong(0),
    "pointsChangedOnYield" : NumberLong(0),
    "pointsRemovedOnYield" : NumberLong(0),
        "server" : "xx:27017"
}
```

I have  2d index on latlng, desc index on _id and **compound** indexes.

```
db.markers.ensureIndex({latlng: '2d', _id:-1})
db.markers.ensureIndex({ latlng: '2d' })
db.markers.ensureIndex({ _id: -1 })
```

What I want to achieve is to get markers from a particular area sorted from newest.

Any ideas or suggestions how to do that in much less time than **2.5 seconds**?

Comment: You should take care of the order of your coordinates. The order is longitude then latitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query in MongoDB can only use one index at a time, so it's a case of one or the other - it can't use the 2d index first, then do a sort on the _id index.  In order to use indexes for both the selection and the sort, you would need a compound index like this:

```
db.markers.ensureIndex( { latlng : "2d" , _id : 1 } );
```

Try that, or similar and see how it impacts the results bearing in mind that once you define it, you can remove the original 2d index to save space and that this new index will have to be loaded into memory to be efficient.

Update: as mentioned in the summary, the above did not improve things, and the resulting query results in a scanAndOrder result.  This also happens with range based queries, as explained in this excellent blog post:

http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/

As explained in that post, the usual resolution for range based query performance is to switch the order of the indexes.  However this is currently not possible with geo indexes.  There is a Jira issue already open for this here for voting and tracking purposes:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4247

Comment: I tried this, with the same result (millis: **2430**, nscanned: **242331**, scanAndOrder: true)

Comment: I was afraid of that.  The normal way around this problem (scanAndOrder happening on a range based query, not using the index for sorting) is to have the sort field as the first element of the index to ensure that the sort is effective.  However, currently with geo indexing that is not possible (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4247 is the issue that needs to be tracked on this).  Is there any chance you could try the sort on the application side?

Comment: Thanks for ticket info. In edge case I would load 264k objects into memory and sort them in each request, so this is not fast solution ;)

Comment: Wait, so the geo query is not selective at all?  Or is 264k the subset of results that the geo query would return without the limit?  I was thinking that if the result set from the geo query limited the result set, you could save the sort until later.

Comment: Geo query is selective but if you zoom out on map to see whole world, then I would need to load all 264k markers just to sort them and display latest 1000. Even if the query is very selective at very high zoom it still takes a long time (1155 ms). This is very important because the view of the world is the starting point of my application.

Comment: hmmmm, I can't think of better optimization here based on the description, but there may be changes that can be made to the data or the methodology here that I am not thinking of....you may have more luck if you describe the applications requirements and ask for advice on the user group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en_US&fromgroups#!forum/mongodb-user